# Explicitly token validation

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am developing an Asp.net web Api 2 project and  I am using OAuth. Now I am able to generate token and send it to client. Now how I will send that token to server from client using jQuery ajax call and validated that token **explicitly** and get user information. **I am not using asp.net identity**.

**Code**

```
public class UserModel
{     
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }        
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}

public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        ConfigureOAuth(app);
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);            
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }

    public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
            Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider()
        };

        // Token Generation
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

    }
}

public class SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{        
    public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        // Resource owner password credentials does not provide a client ID.
        if (context.ClientId == null)
        {
            context.Validated();
        }

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        using (AuthRepository _repo = new AuthRepository())
        {
            var user = _repo.FindUser(context.UserName, context.Password);

            if (user == null)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                return;
            }
        }

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "user"));

        context.Validated(identity);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need and should not validate the token manually, just attribute you protected API end point with `[Authorize]` attribute and leave this validation to the framework, if the token is invalid or expired Web API will return 401 and your are good to go.

Regarding sending your obtained token from client application the server, you need to send the token in the **Authorization** header for your request with Bearer scheme `Authorization: Bearer xf7jsjaaa9292....`

Something like the below will help

```
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Bearer YOUR_TOKEN_GOES_HERE");
}
```

So you can use jQuery beforeSend callback to add an HTTP Authorization header.

Btw I guess the sample code is from my blog http://bitoftech.net so feel free to remove the below claims as it is not useful for your case:

```
identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));
identity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "user"));
```

And replace it with this one:

```
identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.UserName));
```